# How can we use the "GET" method for a form, but still hide URL parameters?

Tags: html

So, I have a `form` that contains a `textarea` field and a `submit` button:

```
<form class="popupForPosting">
 <textarea id="postContent" name="postContent" rows="8" cols="80" class="postContent" placeholder="What's going on, <?php echo $firstname ?>?"></textarea>
 <button id="pos" class="pos" onclick="makePost()">Post</button>
</form>
```

When I click my `submit` button, the call gets sent to my AJAX as a request and my `postContent` (whatever is entered in the `textarea` field) gets shown in the URL. I don't want this to happen.

Now, I don't want to use the `POST` method for this form. I want to use the `GET` method, but still hide the parameters displayed in the URL. According to the information and details given, how can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

```
<script>

const makePost(form) {
  const text = form.postContent.value;
  function makePost() {
    var postContent = $("#postContent").val();
    if (postContent.length > 0) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url:"yourposts.php",
        data:{
          postContent: postContent
        },
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){
          if (data == "success") {
            $(".textpostFormat").html(postContent);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
};

document.querySelector(".popupForPosting").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  makePost(this); // passing the form
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please explain why you need to avoid POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answer for you

1. Change the form tag: `action="yourposts.php" method="post"`
2. Give the submit button an name and a value and remove the click handler
3. move your post.php to the top of the page
4. add a test `isset($_POST["submitButtonName"])`
5. empty the form field before returning the page
6. remove all ajax related script

Now the page will save the data if the button is clicked and not if the page is just loaded. The test for content will handler the reload

**Ajax answer**

Using AJAX does not show the data in the URL - just

- remove `onclick="makePost()"`
- use the submit event of the form instead of the click event of a submit button and use `event.preventDefault()`:

NOTE I have wrapped in a load event handler

---

```js
$(function() { // when form is available
  $(".popupForPosting").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // always prevent submit
    const postContent = $("#postContent").val().trim();
    $('#noText').css({visibility:  postContent === "" ? "visible" : "hidden" })
    $("#popUp").toggle(postContent==="")
    if (postContent) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "yourposts.php",
        data: {
          postContent: postContent
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          if (data == "success") {
            $(".textpostFormat").html(postContent);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```